# Nx monorepo - cacheDirectory pointing to environment variable

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nomachine-nx

NX comes with a caching feature, config is done in the nx.json file

I would like to use environment variable to set the cacheDirectory

is it possible to use a system environment variable in the path to cacheDirectory ?
is it possible to use a specific environment variable NX_MY_CACHE_PATH for instance ?

Below and example : Is there a way to tell NX that $HOME must be interpreted and replaced ?

```json
// nx.json
{
  ...
  "tasksRunnerOptions": {
    "default": {
      "runner": "@nrwl/workspace/tasks-runners/default",
      "options": {
        "cacheableOperations": ["build", "lint", "test", "e2e"],
        "cacheDirectory":  "$HOME/workspace/cache_nx"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to do it in a CI environment or in local development environment? (If CI, I could imagine that you write a node.js script here that swaps this placeholder accordingly and then runs the desired nx scripts).

Comment: Hello thx for awsering. Its is for CI and simultaneously for all local developers workstations. Should nx.json differ from CI to develop branch (used in every develop workstation) NX affected feature would not work as intented

Comment: It doesn't really matter where the cache folder is locally. The doc says that nx first looks for the cache locally and if it doesn't find anything it tries to load the remote cache (if it is enabled). I think that what you are trying to do here is not what you actually want (source: https://nx.dev/l/r/core-extended/computation-caching#customizing-the-cache-location)

Comment: No it matters because on the PIC, we have a cache NX that is not inside the node_modules (which is default value). Thus the Path must be exactly the same on the PIC and on developers workstation. If not NX affected considers all NX projects which is not what we want. Enabling the evaluation of an environment variable enables SAME nx.json but different NX cache location depending on PIC or dev workstation. Of course it goes against their NX cloud politics :)

Comment: if that is the case then you can probably do it with your own executor, which then calls this default executor '@nrwl/workspace/tasks-runners/default' (https://nx.dev/l/a/executors/creating-custom-builders).

Comment: Can you explain this executor lead a bit more ? I don't see it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238403/discussion-between-deunz-and-mateusz-klimentowicz).

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot, chat is blocked by company proxy :/

Comment: never mind anyway we moved on